# Windows 10, merge multiple unallocated spaces

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

My disk partition looks like below. What is the ***safest*** way to merge two unallocated spaces (red underlined) together?

[image]

System Details: Windows 10, SSD: 512G

Comment: There is no true 'safe' way. Always backup. You would have to move the three blue partitions in the middle to the left, and therefore moving the first block of free space to the end of the drive.
The simple option would be to just extend C & E to use the free space. Otherwise, to make one large block, I'd use an application called mini tool partition wizard to do this.

Comment: @mt025 Thanks I just downloaded mini tool partition wizard. Playing around with it. Let me know if you can point me to the specific options I should be looking for in the software.

Comment: @DavidPostill or anyone marking this as duplicate. I guess this a bit complicated because it contains recovery partitions in middle that is blocking me to move around.

Comment: It was closed as a duplicate because it’s a duplicate the fact your partitions are aligned in this was doesn’t change that fact or how you merge them.  The duplicate accepted answer is applicable to this question, the duplicate question, has the exact same layout as your disk